# Moving folder within another folder using ruby or shell script?

Tags: ruby, shell

I am having a common folder name `Vijay`, inside which i am having number of folders.

Folder names Ex:

`32`,`032`,`055`,`056`,`095`.

How can I move the folder named `32` inside `032` folder.

Ruby script or shell script i need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get it, you just want to move the "032" folder into the "32" one and nothing else ? Why not simply use `mv` in shell or `FileUtils.move()` in Ruby ?

Comment: You tried anything till now.

Answer (score 4):

You can do as :

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.cp_r("path_to_vijay/32/","path_to_vijay/032/")
```

Read docs [`::cp_r`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp_r)

> Copies src to dest. If src is a directory, this method copies all its contents recursively. **If *dest* is a directory, copies *src* to *dest/src*.**

Example :-

```
require 'fileutils'

# see here the test2 directoy is empty
Dir.glob("#{__dir__}/test2/**/*") # => []
# look at the content of the test1 directory, which will be copied by it
# parent directory to test2
Dir.glob("#{__dir__}/test1/**/*") # => ["/home/arup/Ruby/test1/a.rb"]

FileUtils.cp_r("#{__dir__}/test1/","#{__dir__}/test2/")

# see the test1 directory itself got copied with all its contents to the
# test2/ directory
Dir.glob("#{__dir__}/test2/**/*")  
# => ["/home/arup/Ruby/test2/test1", "/home/arup/Ruby/test2/test1/a.rb"]
```

Answer (score 1):

using system command:

```
`mv 32 032/`
```

alternatively:

```
FileUtils.mv '32', '032/' , :force => true
```

you may want to use their complete path.